# Need for a look up table?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a `people` table and for each person I need to record category i.e. trainer, trainees, customer.

Should I create a look up table for the above categories, or is it ok to put them as fileds in the `people` table? The db will be quite simple, so I think nulls are not a problem.

Comment: Can a peron be in more than one category?

Comment: Both work. Can a person be multiple roles? If not, you could just have a 'role' column. If there's more than a couple roles and they can be multiple I'd pop it into a separate table.

Comment: If you feel adventurous, Class Table Inheritance with each custom fields being in each table.

Answer (score 1):

Its highly recommended you have another table for category and make it a foreign key. This ensures that all the entries are in one of these categories, and if new categories comeup in future, you can easily append them to the category table

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few people and you are sure you will never ever add more and never enhance anything then just do it like you want above and do self joins.

If you want to make sure on standardized input for category, for example, you can hard code it or use the lookup table.

You know your data better than I do so you will know what is right.  Trust your instincts.